# Get the UIScrollView translation in view as the scroll happens?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uipangesturerecognizer

I am trying to intercept the locationInView from the UIScrollView.panGestureRecognizer as the scroll is happening.

I was able to get the initial touch coordinates (when the scroll begins) implementing the following code inside the delegate method

```
#pragma mark UIScrollViewDelegate
- (void) scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
CGPoint point = [scrollView.panGestureRecognizer locationInView:scrollView];
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(point));}
```

Is there a way to get the coordinates continuously as the scroll is happening? I understand that the scrollView.panGestureRecognizer is a UIPanGestureRecognizer @property of the UIScrollView object, so there should be a panGestureDetected @selector somewhere.

Thx in advance.... e

Comment: You are informed constantly that the scroll is happening in the UIScrollViewDelegate (i.e. `scrollViewDidScroll:`). So do whatever you like there.

Comment: And of course the `contentOffset` tells you the scroll position at any time.

Comment: Thx Matt. I was looking for a way to make a touchMoved method coexist with the panGesture @property within the UIScrollView.

Answer (score 3):

Add the UIScrollViewDelegate method:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

And in there you can access the scrollView while it is scrolling. If you are not using a view that subclasses UIScrollView, be sure to explicitly implement the UIScrollViewDelegate. I assume that you should not have to since the delegate method in your question is being called but I just thought I would point that out.

Be sure you really want to use the `locationInView:` method because it will return the point of the gesture and not the `contentOffset` of the UIScrollView. In other words, the gesture point may be outside of the desired range, where the `contentOffset` is in direct relation to the UIScrollView object.

**EDIT:**

Just as an FYI, the method will be called *a lot*, so make sure you are not doing any heavy processing every time the method is called.